# Always (deep)clone before sending to other tier entites geting from entityManager?

Tags: java, database, jpa, entitymanager

Is there an example for a real-world application when you can send between 3 tiers (ui-business-persistance layer) the same object? For example for the sake of simplicity let it be the entity beans.

I mean if am getReference() from my entityManager and send to the user and i am let the user to be able to edit it, create it, and not copy in any point of my code?

Is there any concurrent or any know issue if you choose this option? 
What is the drawback of this option??

I know there would be nice if we wrapped the object, this way we can attach, package entites, and can travel the object in one object maybe responseItem, we can attach other attributes like dirty flag, but if i want to keep simplicity is it possible? Or EntityManagers will mess up the whole thing? (i feel they will and cant handle e.g. detached objects properly so it is better to encapsulation the whole persistance and UI tier and deep copy them....)

Thanks any answer.

Comment: Why can't you just em.find() your entity and em.merge() it later to persist the changes made in the UI?

Comment: because it is not working at the moment! Clients see other edited entites, entites can not randomly merged (entityManager can't see the differences between the persisted entity and the detached one).  And i only want to find where active flag is 1, so custom query is needed this is also changes thing a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer in this book :   [Pro JPA 2
Mastering the Java™ Persistence API](http://www.apress.com/9781430219569)

I think the main reason is the concurrent thread acces for deep copy entities, referencing to this:

> Applications may not access an entity directly from multiple threads
>   while it is managed by a persistence context. An application may
>   choose, however, to allow entities to be accessed concurrently when
>   they are detached. If it chooses to do so, the synchronization must be
>   controlled through the methods coded on the entity. Concurrent entity
>   state access is not recommended, however, because the entity model
>   does not lend itself well to concurrent patterns. **It would be**
>    **preferable to simply copy the entity and pass the copied entity to**
>    **other threads for access and then merge any changes back into a**
>    **persistence context when they need to be persisted**